# "reverse" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

From [this cool post](http://www.blogohblog.com/cool-javascript-tricks/), one of the pieces of code is:

```
javascript:function flood(n) {if (self.moveBy) {for (i = 200; i >
0;i--){for (j = n; j > 0; j--) {self.moveBy(1,i);
self.moveBy(i,0);self.moveBy(0,-i); self.moveBy(-i,0); } }
}}flood(6);{ var inp = "D-X !msagro na dah tsuj resworb rouY"; var
outp = ""; for (i = 0; i <= inp.length; i++) {outp =inp.charAt (i)
+ outp ; } alert(outp) ;}; reverse
```

What is this `reverse` at the very end?

**Edited Formatted Code From Above:**

```
javascript:function flood(n) {
  if (self.moveBy) {
    for (i = 200; i >0;i--) {
      for (j = n; j > 0; j--) {
        self.moveBy(1,i);
        self.moveBy(i,0);
        self.moveBy(0,-i); 
        self.moveBy(-i,0); 
      }
    }
  }
}
flood(6); 
{
  var inp = "D-X !msagro na dah tsuj resworb rouY"; 
  var outp = ""; 
  for (i = 0; i <= inp.length; i++) {
    outp =inp.charAt (i) + outp ; 
  } 
  alert(outp);
}; 
reverse
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not part of the javascript. It's a Reference Error most likely. Or in the context of the site, it's a typo.

Comment: Awesome a downvote! @Randomblue, it is variable that is referenced that doesn't exist.

Comment: It means there is no element called reverse. It is a typo, doesn't do anything and probably was not meant to be included with the code.